# Anime in '90s where the main character transforms into red armor with a magical silver box

Tags: saint-seiya

I can't find my favorite childhood anime that was shown on Cartoon Network back in the '90s.

The characters looked similar to Dragon Ball's, so it was probably a Japanese Toonami show. The hero is a warrior who has a magical silver box which when opens, some kind of a red armor fits on his arms and legs and gives him super fighting powers.

Also, this wasn't a cyborg show or space related show. Plus, the characters were only humans.

I have searched everywhere possible, copied all titles I found into Google Image trying to find an image that would lead me to the name of the anime for 3 days but no success.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You might try looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Cartoon_Network#Former_acquired_series (or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Toonami#Anime if it was on Toonami). The only one I saw at a glance that it could possibly be is [Ronin Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronin_Warriors) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [**Saint Seiya**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Seiya) (a.k.a. *Knights of the Zodiac* in NA).

[image]

[image]

Comment: you got the right one, thank you very much for your help. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds kind of like [Ronin Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronin_Warriors) and the red armor guy is named [Ryo](http://roninwarriors.wikia.com/wiki/Ryo_of_the_Wildfire)

[image]